# Does performance time depend on CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, performance

aSuppose I have following HTML

```
        <div class="xyz">
           ......
        </div>
        <div class="abc">
           ......
        </div>
        <p>
           .....
        </p>
        <div class="xyz">
           ......
        </div>
        <div class="abc">
           ......
        </div>
```

And following css:

```
.xyz{
      background:#cccccc;
}
```

Now IF I CHANGE css to more specific:

```
div.xyz{
          background:#cccccc;
    }
```

Does it affect any in terms of required performance time?

Can you please elaborate why?

Comment: Almost everything affects performance.

Comment: This is the third question about the performance of CSS selectors I've seen this weekend. What's with the sudden obsession with them?

Comment: @Quentin: Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Quentin Many people believe their site is slow due to their selector logic, while in fact it's slow because of their general structure logic. Snake oil.

Comment: @Nit — I know why people worry in general, but I don't remember seeing a question on the subject in months, and then three come along in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

But the effect is so tiny that you will not notice it.

More components to a selector means more things to check before determining if an element matches.

Comment: this checking is synchronous or asynchronous ?? I mean when these checks done??

Answer (score 1):

When searching for performance issues, normally CSS is the last you should check.

The most important parts for performance are the file sizes (JavaScript, CSS, Images, …), the number of files that are loaded (again JavaScript, CSS, Images, …) and the load order (CSS should be in the `<head>`, JavaScript—if possible—just before the closing `<body>` tag), performance of JavaScript code (Loops, CSS selectors in jQuery, possible memory leaks).

### edit

if you are worried about CSS performance, here is a [mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) and a [second one](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/) and on from [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering?csw=1)

Comment: Some of the links which might help OP.. [link1](http://gtmetrix.com/) and [link2](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

Comment: @LogicBurner np :). this [**link**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/46716/68702) might also help you.